# Perl script to make last 4 characters of file name all caps

Tags: perl

What would the line be that makes the last 4 characters of a file name all caps? I am trying to take a file name from a.) gh4567_yh7l_jk12 to b.) gh4567_yh7l_JK12 I need it to make the last four characters all caps without changing the first characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "folder path";

@files = `ls *.tif`; chomp @files;

foreach $oldname (@files)
{
    $newname = $oldname;
    #$newname =~ s/(^.{1,8})/\U$1/e;
    $newname =~ s/(^.{8})/uc($1)/e;

    print "$oldname -> $newname\n";
    rename("$oldname","$newname");
}
```

Comment: I am really new. So far I was thinking  $newname =~ s/({4}.^)/uc($1)/e;

Comment: @user1295706: edit that into your question, and explain why this doesn't do what you want (i.e. show sample input, output, and what you  wanted as output)

Comment: Here is what I have tried, but I dont think it is correct: #!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory path";

@files = `ls *.tif`; chomp @files;

foreach $oldname (@files)
{
 $newname = $oldname;
 $newname =~ s/(^.{8})/uc($1)/e;
 
 print "$oldname -> $newname\n";
 rename("$oldname","$newname");
}

Comment: @user1295706: use the "edit" link right under the tags to put all that information into your question. Code is unreadable in comments. And why do you say "I don't think it is correct"? Does it work? If not, what does it do wrong? (You _really_ need to explain that.)

Comment: @user1295706: nearly there. What does that code _do_? Please post sample input and output, and what you want as output.

Comment: Perl's built-in `glob` will get you a list of files. You don't need `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc?perlre.html).

[Limited answer on account of it being homework and on account of the lack of effort.]